# Does SSRS report caching use the cache during the multiple rows that are returned by data driven reports?

Tags: reporting-services

I will be implementing a data driven report in SSRS 2019 that will have over 80 "TO" receiving email addresses all as individually returned rows in the subscription's caching dataset.

Background; They are individual rows because if you put all the email addresses in a single "TO", and one email address is undeliverable, report server will try to resend the whole report 3 more times at 15 min intervals. So, the everyone receives the report 3 more times while the failing email address never gets it. I know the report server can be set to not retry failed attempts, but out server administrators are unwilling to do that.

So, my question is: Will the subscription's first "TO" email address, from the caching dataset, cache the report for use by the next 79? Or, will all 80 get generated individually and caching only begin/benefit the subscriptions (or a user) who runs the report later within the caching timeframe?

thanks
Gord

Comment: As far as I know, as long as the parameters (if any) remain the same, the report will use the cache or snapshot (if one is available). See this article for more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/set-report-processing-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Yeah, that article says "if ten users open the report, only the first request results in report processing.". I'm not sure that's the same as one report request for 10 deliveries.

Comment: As I said, I think if the parameters are the same (or if there are none) then it should use the cached version of the data. You could test it out by checking the dbo.ExecutionLog table (or one of the system views based on this table) . If it does not specify it directly, you would be able to tell by looking at the data processing time, it should be much shorter for all but the first execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alan for reminding me about the ExecutionLog views.

I ran a test data driven subscription to 5 email addresses.

Looks like report server is processing them in batches and once **one** of the first reports in the first batch is complete, a cached copy is created/available for any further reports to use.

In the table below, the report in the second row completes in 5.299 seconds, after row 4 has started but before row 5 starts... so row 5 uses the cache.

| TimeStart | TimeDataRetrieval | Source | RowCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2023-01-27 08:02:22.463** | 5625 | Live | 803 |
| **2023-01-27 08:02:22.493** | 5299 | Live | 803 |
| **2023-01-27 08:02:22.493** | 6197 | Live | 803 |
| 2023-01-27 08:02:25.573 | 8853 | Live | 803 |
| 2023-01-27 08:02:43.307 | 0 | **Cache** | 0 |